# Check for specific tag does not work on tag- and archive-page - solution?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a certain element (for example just the word "HELLO") in the header area of all pages and use PHP operators to exclude certain pages from the display of this element. In my case this element ("Hello") should NOT be displayed if a post has the tag with the ID 4444 or if it is in category with the ID 123 or 456.

The sample code that is in the header and also works correctly:

```
if ( !in_category ( array (123, 456)) && !has_tag (4444)):

echo '<div class=\'example\'>Hello</div>';

endif;
```

The example text "Hello" should therefore be displayed in every post and on every page that does NOT have the keyword ID 4444 in the categories with IDs 123 and/or 456 and/or NOT the keyword ID 4444.

This works wonderfully on all pages and also in every post.

BUT (and this is the problem), if I look at the archive or a tag page (both of which are represented by archive.php) or if I use the search (search.php), it doesn't work correctly. If the archive, tag or search page lists multiple article previews and the TOP (!) article has, for example, assigned a tag with the ID 4444, the word "Hello" is NOT displayed in the header of the archive, tag or search page - but it should be!

If such an article preview (whose article e.g. has the tag ID 4444) is in second, third or later position, then "Hello" is displayed in the header.

I don't want to search for ID 4444 or category 123, 456 on archive, tag or search pages because they are just pages that list article previews. On these pages, however, "Hello" should be displayed as desired in the header.

Comment: Hi - dajana - I'm guess it will be easy to solve your issue once you've clarified it - that is, if you laid out the desired result schematically, even a bit redundantly - with page type, particular condition or conditions, desired result - explained as precisely and unambiguously as possible, maybe even the form of a chart or anyway a series of clear statements.

Comment: I'm still having trouble following your description. You know that you can edit your original question, right? If you included a larger sample of the code you're using, including how/where it's being called, commented as needed, it might be easier to sort things out, though I can't promise the answer will be immediately clear on the first go.

Comment: I did not know that I can edit my original post, sorry.

Comment: @CK MacLeod I updated my thread. Now it should be 100% clear ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(edited after comment)*

I think it's simple and all you want is this:

```
//if on any archive or archive-like page OR on "singular" pages except as excluded
if ( ! is_singular() || ( is_singular() && ! in_category( array (123, 456)) && ! has_tag (4444) ) ):

echo '<div class=\'example\'>Hello</div>';

endif;
```

I rarely worry about attachment pages at all, frankly, but, to specifically involve them, you could work in `is_attachment()` OR `is_page()` and `is_single()`

For more on Wordpress conditional tags go here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

A second alternative, but I wouldn't really recommend it, is to use CSS to hide the element on specific pages/page-types.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That doesn't solve the problem - it's practically the same as I have at the moment. This "Hello" should also appear on the archive, tag and search pages as well. That's the actual problem as described - it's about the fact that it only works on these pages if the first article in the list is NOT linked to the specific tag ID. CSS is not an option for me.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I was just joking about the project being unsolvable. I've amended my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I just wrote that your suggestion didn't solve the problem and practically does the same thing as in my code. It doesn't change the behavior on search, archive and tag pages.

Comment: Oh wait screwed something up... Will get to this in a bit

Comment: Just to be sure I installed the edited version of the code on one of my own sites, and it works as expected: It shows on archive and search pages and on all posts/pages except for ones in the category-to-be-excluded.